# Netlify manual deploy failed

Tags: deployment, netlify

I'm using Netlify to host my static website. When I try to deploy, error message come out:

```
Looks like something went wrong!
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, try refreshing.
```

- Note: I'm deploying manually via dragging the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I found the answer!

I waited like for 30 minutes, and your site is deployed!